# Asympototic solution

Tags: asymptotics

Asked to find ﬁrst three terms in the local behavior as $x\to 0^+$ of the solutions of $\displaystyle{y'+ xy = \frac{1}{x^3}}$

This was taken by bender and orszag book

Working :

I tried to use method of dominance but later realised that we can find using the series expansion. But I am not sure how to proceed. Please advise how to proceed with it.

Comment: If that can help, $y=e^{-x^2/2}\left(C-\displaystyle\int\dfrac{e^{x^2/2}}{2x^2}dx\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Taylor expansion of the constant

Since this equation is linear the simplest way to find asymptotic behaviour is to try to estimate the asymptotic behaviour of the *constant* while applying the *variation of constant* method.

So first you solve the homegeneous equation : $y'+xy=0\iff y=A\,e^{-x^2/2}$.

Then applying constant variation : $\require{cancel}\displaystyle{\frac{1}{x^3}=y'+xy=\cancel{-Ax\,e^{-x^2/2}}+A'e^{-x^2/2}+\cancel{Ax\,e^{-x^2/2}}}$

We get $\displaystyle{A'(x)=\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^3}}=\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)\right)/x^3=\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{2x}+\frac x8+o(x)$

We integrate this $\displaystyle{A(x)=B-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{\ln(x)}{2}+\frac{x^2}{16}+o(x^2)}$

And multiply the by $\displaystyle{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)}$

Finally $\displaystyle{y(x)=B-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{\ln(x)}{2}+\frac{x^2}{16}-\frac{Bx^2}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{x^2\ln(x)}{4}+o(x^2)}$

If we limit ourselves to $3$ terms as asked then $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid ]{\displaystyle{y(x)=-\frac{1}{2x^2}+C+\frac{\ln(x)}{2}+o(x)}}$ with $C\in\mathbb R$ near $0^+$.

---

#### Method of dominant balance

There are no negligible term in our equation.

But let's set $\displaystyle{g(x)=y(x)+\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac12\ln(x)}\qquad(*)$

*According to previous study we have to show that $g(x)\to C$*

Rem: to find $(*)$ just do it incrementaly, negliglate $xy$, solve, and so on, until rhs do not diverge to infinity anymore.

We have $\displaystyle{g'=y'-\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{2x}=-xy-\frac{1}{2x}=\left(-xg+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac x2\ln(x)\right)-\frac{1}{2x}}$

So $\displaystyle{g'+xg=-\frac{x\ln(x)}{2}}\to 0$ when $x\to 0^+\quad$ now this equation has something negligible.

The homegeneous equation $g'+xg=0$ gives $g=A.e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\to A$ when $x\to 0$.

This is working but I feel that this method is full of fluff compared to first method.

Comment: Ok..Thank you for making me understand:)